# How to add a Facebook @friend with SLComposeViewController

Tags: ios, facebook, slcomposeviewcontroller

I am using `SLComposeViewController` to compose a text to share on Facebook.
I would like to automatically add my company name (similar to @ while in Facebook.).
So it would look like:
".... @company"
and the @company would be a link to the Facebook page of the company.

current code:

```
SLComposeViewController *mySLComposerSheet = nil;
NSString* shareString = @"I just used app from @company";
mySLComposerSheet = [[SLComposeViewController alloc] init]; //initiate the Social Controller
mySLComposerSheet = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook];
[mySLComposerSheet setInitialText:shareString];
[self presentViewController:mySLComposerSheet animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: Same problem , Have you got solution?